# Applying parallax effect to text

Tags: jquery, parallax

I have applied a parallax effect for background, but I also want to apply similar effect to text, so it scrolls independently to the rest, so for example faster than the background and the page itself. Here is the code I have:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

var parall = document.querySelectorAll('.parall'),
    speed = -0.4;

window.onscroll = function(){
  [].slice.call(parall).forEach(function(el,i){

    var windowYOffsets = window.pageYOffset,
        elBackgrounPos = '50%' + (windowYOffsets * speed) + 'px';

    el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;

  });
};

});
```

```css
.parall {
  background: url("https://www.tucado.com/images/marketing-solutions-bg.jpg") center top no-repeat;
  height: 275px;
  top: 0px;
  background-attachment: fixed !important;
}

.parall h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-size: 100px;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parall">
  <h1 class="parallsec">TEXT</h1>
</div>
```

I want h1 (.parallsec) to scroll independently, but the jquery code I have works only with the background.

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tucado/bn3guh4o/5/)

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: I think you should use a proper event handler like `window.on('scroll', function() {` rather than an inline version. In your example the second `window.onscroll` will overwrite the initial attribute.

Comment: Thanks Rory, is there a chance you can drop it on jsfiddle? Thanks

Comment: Two documents ready. No need for that as you can add everything in one callback. But primarily what @Shikkediel says. Look how you implemented the `ready` event. The same way you have to implement the `scroll` event, and notice how dumb is to have 2 events attached at the same time when you can do everything in one event (2 readys and 2 scroll). With this you should solve your problem. You are a smart guy :P

Comment: Thanks JorgeFuentesGonzalez I have removed the second document ready, but still don't know how to apply parallax effect to h1. I'm not very familiar with jquery.

Comment: In addition to my earlier comment, you'd also have to set a `translate` (for example) on the second parallax instead of a `background-position`. [Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opJNwz?editors=1010).